# Docker Desktop : Stuck on 'Starting Docker Engine' 2024

Tags: windows, docker, image, containers, command-line-interface

I've tried reinstalling and running as admin (on windows laptop). I haven't created any of my own images/containers, I've used to welcome-to-docker images and it crashed after a few hours. I can't even access the setting since the engine is not loading.

[Img of docker not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXiVP.png)

## Reasons why I think its not working

On PowerShell (as admin) after running
`docker ps`

This error shows up

```
request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json, check if the server supports the requested API version
```

and
`docker list`

This error

```
request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version, check if the server supports the requested API version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35+desktop.5
 Version:           24.0.7
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.10
 Git commit:        afdd53b
 Built:             Thu Oct 26 09:08:44 2023
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
```

So the issue lies within the server side/docker daemon? I'm not sure what to do from here on since I can only use the CLI and not docker desktop itself and I've tried to find resources to match the API version with docker desktop version (24.0.7) but no luck.

Please any help would be great!

I've tried reinstalling, unregistering wsl, disabling and enabling Hyper-V, checked and I do have containers and Hyper-V checked on windows functions, running everything as admin.